# Java MenuBar cuts into my applet

Tags: java, awt, menubar

Simple question - I am editting a java based MMORPG game and wanted to add a menubar to the gameframe. So I did, but the menubar seems to cut into the game and block some of the content so that it is hidden behind the menubar. There is an example picture right here:

[image: example picture]

And here is a picture of my code:

```
public GameFrame(GameWindow gameWindow, int width, int height, String title, boolean resizable, boolean flag1) {
    frameOffset = 28;
    frameWidth = width;
    frameHeight = height - 1;
    aGameWindow = gameWindow;
    addListeners(this, gameWindow);
    if (flag1)
        frameOffset = 48;
    else
        frameOffset = 28;
    setTitle(title);
    setResizable(resizable);

    menubar = new MenuBar();
    menu = new java.awt.Menu("Menu");
    submenu = new java.awt.Menu("Sub Menu");

    m1 = new MenuItem("Menu Item 1");
    m2 = new MenuItem("Menu Item 2");
    m3 = new MenuItem("Menu Item 3");
    m4 = new MenuItem("Menu Item 4");
    m5 = new MenuItem("Menu Item 5");

    menu.add(m1);
    menu.add(m2);
    menu.add(m3);

    submenu.add(m4);
    submenu.add(m5);

    menu.add(submenu);
    menubar.add(menu);

    setMenuBar(menubar);

    this.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {
        @Override
        public void windowActivated(WindowEvent arg0) {}

        @Override
        public void windowClosed(WindowEvent arg0) {
            System.exit(-1);            
        }

        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0) {
            System.exit(-1);                
        }

        @Override
        public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent arg0) {}
        @Override
        public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent arg0) {}
        @Override
        public void windowIconified(WindowEvent arg0) {}
        @Override
        public void windowOpened(WindowEvent arg0) {}
    });
    show();
    toFront();
    resize(frameWidth, frameHeight);
    aGraphics49 = getGraphics();
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this problem, or create some extra space up top so that it wont interfere with the game?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us  the layout code encompassing both the menu and the game area?

Comment: You are probably building the GUI incorrectly. Make sure you add the JMenuBar to the frame using  `frame.setJMenuBar()` method. And make sure you add your game panel to the content pane of the frame using `frame.add( yourGamePanel );`. If you need more help then post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating the problem because we don't have the time to guess what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Okay added the code there. Also, im using AWT, not Swing

Comment: `Also, im using AWT, not Swing` - So why do your tags say `Swing` and `JMenu`? Also, you still haven't posted a proper SSCCE. Good luck with your problem I don't have time to guess what you are doing.

Comment: The 4 lines ending in `aGraphics49 = getGraphics();` are either very questionable or downright wrong.  Whatever source you are using to learn Java, ignore it and use the Oracle tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a JMenuBar, just do a MenuBar. It will show a menu bar that is above the GUI and will allow your full screen of the GUI to be shown...it acts as a JMenuBar in every way..

```
MenuBar mB = new MenuBar();
Menu menu = new Menu("Menu");
MenuItem mI1 = new MenuItem("Menu Item 1");

// setting the bar
this.setMenuBar(mB);

//adding the menu onto the bar
mB.addMenu(menu);

// adding the menu item into the menu
menu.addMenuItem(mI1);

//adding action listener
mI1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // do whatever
    }
});
```

You can see much more here:

[MenuBar, Menu, and MenuItem help](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/adiehelp/v5r1m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.sun.api.doc/java/awt/MenuBar.AccessibleAWTMenuBar.html)

Comment: AWT MenuBar will not help him, being a heavyweight component just means nothing else will be able to obstruct it - but it will still render.

Comment: well he said he was using AWT, so I figured he should be using the proper objects instead of Swing inside AWT

Comment: funny - looking at the code he pasted he is already using AWT all over the place.

Comment: that's before he changed his MenuBar...etc. Before, he was using JMenuBar and JMenu and JMenuItem and others

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a pause menu using a Jpanel. Every good game needs a pause menu :).

Make sure if you go this route give the JPanel a keyListener so you may setVisible when you press a determined key.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the game panel does not respect the insets.
instead of adding the menubar to the GameFrame itself, create a top level panel - put the GameFrame inside it at BorderLayout.CENTER and add the menubar to the top level panel.
then add that panel to your applet instead of adding the GameFrame directly.